# Cannot Locate the file in AWS EMR Notebook

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-efs

I have been trying to use some `.txt`, `.csv` files in an EMR Notebook but I cannot locate them.

I am trying to read via:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    notes = f.read()
```

Things I tried:

- Uploaded the file by using JupyterHub UI. I can see the file but I cant read it from the path. I also checked the file using JupyterHub terminal.
- Tried  to read from s3 (lots of people got it working in this way):

  `with open('s3://<repo>/file.txt', 'r') as f:`
- Copied the file to `hdfs` and `hadoop` in master node (in cluster) using both: `hdfs dfs` and `hadoop fs` . File is present in both directories.

However, I have no clue how I can reach the file in EMR Notebook.

Any ideas?

Comment: vagitus do you have output